# How to replicate the tons transported from Belgium to France in 2022 using Eurostat?

Tags: transportation, europe

The european union statistics institution performs a survey on road freight statistics:
https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/en/road_go_esms.htm

As a result they presented a country-to-country flow table in one of their transport statistics articles:
[country-to-country freight flow](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=File:Top_20_country-to-country_flows_in_intra-EU_road_freight_transport,_2022_(million_tonnes).png)

I'm trying to replicate that table using their datasets. After handling data input and preprocessing I filter the datasets the following way:

```
lgtt = lgtt[(lgtt.tra_type=="TOTAL") &
    (lgtt.unit=="THS_T") &
    (lgtt.nst07=="TOTAL") & 
    (lgtt.TIME_PERIOD=="2022")&
    (lgtt.c_unload.str.len() == 2)]

ugtt = ugtt[(ugtt.tra_type=="TOTAL") &
        (ugtt.unit=="THS_T") &
        (ugtt.nst07=="TOTAL") & 
        (ugtt.TIME_PERIOD=="2022")&
        (ugtt.c_load.str.len() == 2)]

cross = cross[(cross.tra_type=="TOTAL") &
        (cross.unit=="THS_T") &
        (cross.nst07=="TOTAL") & 
        (cross.TIME_PERIOD=="2022")&
        (cross.c_load.str.len() == 2)&
        (cross.c_unload.str.len() == 2)]
```

Here is a complete github repo with the code and the data:
https://github.com/Italosayan/eurostat_road/blob/main/eurostat_intra_eu_trade_2022.py

I get 31.8 M tons of freight but 56.6 M is the reported value in the article. I've been calling the EU and trying all sorts of aggregations but without any success.

---

Extra info:

[Methodology Docs](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/3859598/8134263/KS-GQ-16-105-EN-N.pdf/fcd315ef-0439-4f9c-ae51-90735c2c1dc1?t=1556113080000)

[Survey info](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/microdata/european-road-freight-transport-survey)